# Can Lion Automount Drives When They're Connected to Time Capsule?

Tags: external-hard-drive, automount, time-capsule

Is there a way to detect when external drives are connected to a Time Capsule, and mount them automatically?

I have 3 external drives tied to a Time Capsule via a USB hub. Most of the time they are powered down.  I want OS X (Lion) to mount them when the drives are powered up.  Possible?